# Passing data from static table inside second controller to first view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates, segue

I working on alarm clock app and Im trying to pass data from B controller (the one in the middle of picture) to the previous one (which is A) . As you can see B view controller contains UIView which is “filled” with static table view controller (C).

I can pass data back from the B to A with delegate , it works fine, but I don’t know how pass data from the C to A (using segue and delegates?). C controller is inside B controller.

I just tried simply with segue (As you can see I created segue between C and A) and delegate, but It didn’t work and I really don’t know if it’s the good idea or practice.

To call protocol method I use this code in C controller (function parameter is just for testing purposes):

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        self.delegate?.passAlarmSettings(test: 1)

    }
```

Or maybe I should pass from C to B and then from B to A? Or is any better way to do it?
Thanks for any suggestions

[image]

Comment: Add a variable in B like `cViewController` assign it in segue method, then use you delegate passing B  to A.

Comment: You don't want a segue between A and C. What I would do is use a closure. A would pass the closure to B, then B would pass the closure to C. When C is ready, just invoke the closure so A can handle the call. Another option is to use [notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter).

Comment: not sure what I did is right, but I just simply created delegates in C and B. When C viewController disappears it passes data to B and it automatically passes it to A viewController. The delegate method in class C is called in viewWillDisapear() and in B class in dismiss (completion). What bother me is if dismiss() in B is called before viewWillDisapear() in C class (and the delegate). But it's working so far and data are passed from C to A.